# Target class [Admin\UserController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have separated my project routes into `home.php` that contains the client-side routes and `admin.php` that contains server-side routes.

So here is my `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/home.php'));

            Route::middleware(['web', 'auth.admin'])
                ->namespace($this->namespace . '\Admin')
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
        });
    }
```

So as you see I have specified `->namespace($this->namespace . '\Admin')` because of Admin Controllers that are placed in this directory:

`App\Http\Controllers\Admin\...`

Then in the `admin.php`, I added this route:

```
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

But I get this error:

```
Target class [Admin\UserController] does not exist.
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue and properly call the Controller from Admin?

Comment: Can you add that full UserController file here ....checkout the namespace of that userController also..

Comment: @SaravanaSai It has this namespace: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;`

Comment: Have you properly imported on your routes file check i out ...i think its should b e something like this  'Route::resource('users',App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ UserController::class); '   try it out this

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add a `use` statement to point out where your controller lies within the route file.

For example:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController;
```

Answer (score 0):

The namespace changes are correct.

The problem is a missing using.

So to correct it, change in your route file:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController; // <-- add this.

Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust this for the `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace('\App\Http\Controllers')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/home.php'));

            Route::middleware(['web', 'auth.admin'])
                ->namespace('\App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
        });
    }
```

And then you can run this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```